# Problem reading an Integer in java that was written using python’s struct.pack method

Tags: java, python

First I write the integer using python:
`out.write( struct.pack(">i", int(i)) );`

I then read the integer using `DataInputStream.readInt()` in Java.
I works but when it tries to read the number 10, and probably some other numbers too,
it starts to read garbage.
Reading the numbers:
`0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 13, 10, 1, 5, 6`
Java reads:
`0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 13, 167772160, 16777216, 83886080`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Psychic debugging: You're writing the output in text mode on Windows using code like this:

```
f = open("output.dat", "w")
f.write(my_data)
```

and that's making your 13 (which is a newline) become carriage return / newline (10, 13).

You need to write your output in binary mode:

```
f = open("output.dat", "wb")
f.write(my_data)
```

Comment: Of course! You have to write in binary mode to write binary data.
That didn't even cross my mind.
Thanks.